# How to get IV from AES encryption in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, encryption, aes, password-encryption

I am new to AES encryption.
I am using following java code for encrypting my password and it works fine.

```
private void startEncryption() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String text = "15";
    String key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String ivString = "LXUJOLKDEJKGTMAV";
    byte[] valueBytes = text.getBytes();
    byte[] keyBytes = keyString.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] ivBytes = ivString.getBytes();
    byte[] ivFinalBytes = new byte[16];
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++){
        ivFinalBytes[i] = ivBytes[i];
    }
    encrypt(valueBytes, keyBytes, ivFinalBytes);
}

private void encrypt(byte[] valueBytes, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] ivBytes) {
    try {
        SecretKeySpec ks = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ks, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] clearText = c.doFinal(valueBytes);
        String ivPass = Base64.encodeToString(c.getIV(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        String pass = Base64.encodeToString(clearText, Base64.DEFAULT);
        encryptedPassword = ivPass+pass;
        encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception: "+e);
    }
}
```

Output looks like following:

```
azhTMrwGqTN21O4oRenR6Q==VE5LTU9GT1BCWldRSEREQQ==
```

Now I am trying to do same thing in objective C. Following is the code which i am using right now:

```
-(NSString*)testActuallyEncrypting:(NSString *)data
{
    NSString *key  = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    NSString *iv = @"LXUJOLKDEJKGTMAV";
    NSData *dataIn  = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *keyData = [key  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *ivData = [iv dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus   = kCCSuccess;
    size_t          cryptBytes = 0;
    NSMutableData  *dataOut    = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataIn.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
    ccStatus = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt,
                   kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                   kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                   keyData.bytes, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                   ivData.bytes,
                   dataIn.bytes, dataIn.length,
                   dataOut.mutableBytes, dataOut.length,
                   &cryptBytes);
    if (ccStatus != kCCSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"CCCrypt status: %d", ccStatus);
    }
    dataOut.length = cryptBytes;
    NSString *objcEncrypted = [dataOut base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSLog(@"objcEncrypted: %@", objcEncrypted);
    return objcEncrypted;
}
```

Seems like I am getting the right encrypted password. 
    VE5LTU9GT1BCWldRSEREQQ==

How can I get IV which should be like azhTMrwGqTN21O4oRenR6Q==?

Comment: You should hash passwords, not encrypt them!

Comment: Thanks. Infact I am only making an app. Encryption is what client wants.

Comment: Well it's a good thing you advised your client how poor of an idea that is then!

Comment: I will surely do that. Thanks :)

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gains access he will also get the encryption key. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and adding following line of codes solved my problem:

```
NSString *ivEncrypted = [ivData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSString *encryptedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", ivEncrypted, objcEncrypted];
```

and then return encryptedString

Comment: It would be better to join the IV and encrypted data prior to Base64 encoding.